# Xcode swipe to navigate between pages of content

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to know how to do something like swiping left/right when user is looking at one view that is a story/content, then it goes either back or forward to the next content, of x of y pages.

Something like how the CNN iOS app do, with a row of small circles to indicate where the user is looking at now.

Is the swipe gesture recognizer from the Xcode the main factor to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

This ui element is called [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: so the UIPagecontrol, can it be used on a UIWebView or just on a normal ViewController?

Comment: You can add any view to the page controller, including UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)scrollView
 {

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
 [scrollView setScrollsToTop:YES];

 scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;

 scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*totalPages,460);
 scrollView.delegate = self;

 [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

}

```
-(void)makePages
{

 for (int i=0; i<totalPages; i++) 
 {
    containerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320*i,0,320,460)];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    containerView.tag = i;

    if(i%2 == 0)
        containerView.backGroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
     else
        containerView.backGroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

 }

[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460) animated:YES];

 }
```